# 「しり目に」の意味は何ですか。

Tags: words

下の文章で「しり目に」の意味は何ですか。

例）「たなびく白い雲をしり目に、大きなかたまりがぐんぐんと空におしのぼっている。」

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 辞書を引いたら？ （１５字以上の制限・・・）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/112621/meaning/m0u/)には、「『…をしりめに』の形で、その場のようすをちらっと見てあとは構わず自分の行動を進めるさま。例『同僚の慰留をしりめに会社をやめた』」と書いてあります。

この例文だと、「たなびく白い雲を置き去りにして、大きなかたまり(の雲)がぐんぐんと空におしのぼっている。」と言う意味だと思います。